# How to insert a chunk of html?

Tags: pug

How do I include a multi-line chunk of html text as-is in a Jade template?

`|.` does not seem to work like `someTag.` would.

Comment: Why does `someTag.` not work for you? See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/gxLoMG). Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I think you misread.  `someTag.`, eg `p.` works, that is I can put a chunk of text, including html, as the content for `<someTag>`.  But vertical bar and period, `|.`, does allow me to put more than one line of text.

Answer (score 0):

`|` works in your case.

```
body
    | <div><a href="#"> test</a></div>
```

Comment: Oh, I mean a multi-line chunk.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to include the chunk like this:

```
include the-html-file.html
```

I like this approach because it keeps your jade and html separate. Alternatively, you can use a converter like [html2jade](https://github.com/donpark/html2jade) to convert the html into jade.

I would recommend switching to [pug](https://pugjs.org), since jade has been deprecated. I realize it's still technically in beta, but I have yet to run into any bugs. Pug will allow you to simply copy/paste html content into your pug templates, as long as it respects indentation.

```
body
    h1= title
    <div>
        <h1>hello multiline html</h1>
    </div>
```

To answer your question more directly, I believe you can use the bar on multiple lines without the dot, but it becomes cumbersome to write like this.

```
body 
    h1=title
    | <div>
    | <h1> hello multiline html</h1>
    | </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pug 2 (I don't know about earlier versions), you can use a period:

```
p
  strong Some text...
  .
    And <em>more</em> text,
    spanning
    multiple
    lines.
```

Output:

```html
<p><strong>Some text...</strong>And <em>more</em> text,
spanning
multiple
lines.</p>
```